# Dynamic Linking Config in Web 8

Tags: web8, dynamic-linking

I've installed and configured the Content Service to run on port 8088, as the McAfee virus scanner was running on the default port.

In Visual Studio I downloaded the Content Delivery NuGet Package and built the solution.  This gave me a lot of SDL and dependent OData DLLs.  I copied all of them to the bin folder of my .Net Website.

Then, I updated the web.config to reference the Tridion Linking taglib.

Finally, I created a config folder within bin, and copied the cd_storage, ambient configs, logback, etc to this folder.

Linking is not working.

Does the cd_storage need a role?  And if so, what role is that?  Where do I point the .NEt CD "Client" to the Content Service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using REST setup for CD API's, you don't need `cd_storage_conf.xml` at client side.

To make sure that Content Service location can be found by clients,

- Register "ContentServiceCapability" in Discovery service.
- Provide Discovery service URL in `Web.config`of your client application
- Provide ClientId and Client secret (for OAuth) in `Web.config`of your client application